# Problem in importing : import pandas_market_calendars

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, import

After the installation of market calendar, when I import:

```py
import pandas_market_calendars
```

I get following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'apply_wraps' from 'pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets'
```

Answer (score -1):

`import pandas as pd`

`import pandas_market_calendars as mcal`